# Setting a variable with select inside coalesce

Tags: sql, variables, select, sql-server-2000, coalesce

How do I fix up this part of my stored procedure?

The select will either return 1, 0, or null. If the select returns 1 or 0, I want @override to be set to that value. If it returns null, then I want @override to be set to 1.

Something is wrong with my syntax; I am told "incorrect syntax near 'select'" and "incorrect sytax near ')'".

Here is the sql:

```
set @override = (coalesce(select override from groupPreferences g inner join
preferences p on g.preferenceId = p.preferenceId where groupId = 13
and description = 'myDescription'), 1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set @override = (coalesce((select override from groupPreferences g inner join
preferences p on g.preferenceId = p.preferenceId where groupId = 13
and description = 'myDescription'), 1))
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for something readable like this:

```
select @override = override 
from groupPreferences g 
    inner join preferences p on g.preferenceId = p.preferenceId 
where groupId = 13
    and description = 'myDescription'

SET @override = ISNULL(@override, 1)
```

But you can do:

```
SELECT @override = ISNULL((select override 
from groupPreferences g 
    inner join preferences p on g.preferenceId = p.preferenceId 
where groupId = 13
    and description = 'myDescription'), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer- I was missing a ( after the word coalesce.

Comment: Pretty much like bodee's answer?